# Where does Android store system settings such as WiFi networks?

Tags: android, settings

Can't find the databases with the system settings on my device. Where are they located?

Comment: If I remember right it's `/system/etc/wifi`

Comment: It's wpa_supplicant linux conf file, not Android's SQLite database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The settings database is located at `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db`. You cannot access it unless you have root.

Comment: Thanks, I know about root :)

Answer (score 9):

The SSIDs and passwords of the wifi networks are stored to /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: Similarly, Bluetooth networks are stored in /data/misc/bluedroid. Came in handy when I needed to forget a bluetooth custom name, there's no apparent way in the Settings app.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify `/data/misc/apexdata/com.android.wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml`

More information here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20875807

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to pull all your system configuration through root access, then I guess you should look up into

```
/data/system/users/0
```

As everything will be saved there as xml preferences.